# Remove white spacing before chapter styles modified with tcolorbox? (tufte-book)

Tags: chapters, tcolorbox, titlesec, tufte-book

In `tufte-book`, I have defined two `chapter` styles, one without numbering (used in front matter) and one with (used in main matter).

Now, there is unwanted white spacing before each style, as shown in the figure (`showframe` enabled). How to move the chapter to the immediate top of the document? That is, how to remove the unwanted vertical space?

Curiously, the spacing is different for each style. I am wondering what causes this?

Here is the MWE,

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[justified,notoc]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\title{Ngữ âm}
\author{Hiếu Nguyễn}
\publisher{Tự xuất bản}
\usepackage{showframe}
% For nicely typeset tabular material
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\chapBox}[1]{\begin{tcolorbox}
        [
        colback=black!100,% background
        colframe=black,% frame colour
        coltext=white, % text color
        width=\linewidth,%
        height=0.5cm, 
        halign=left,
        valign=center,
        %fontupper=\large\bfseries,
        enlarge top by=0mm,
        enlarge bottom by=0mm,
        arc=0mm, outer arc=0mm,
        ]
    \Large\bfseries\allcaps{#1}
    \end{tcolorbox}}

%%
\titleformat{\chapter}
  [display]
  {\chapBox{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}}
  {}
  {0ex}
  {\vspace{-0.7cm}\fontsize{28}{32}\raggedright\normalfont\color{orange}}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  [display]
  {}
  {}
  {0ex}
  {\chapBox}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{25pt}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{A frontmatter chapter}
\mainmatter
\chapter{A mainmatter chapter}
\end{document}
```

A figure showing what I am talking about.

[image: Different spacing before chapter styles?]

Answer (score 2):

Add to the preamble

```
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{-35pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter}{0pt}{-22pt}{40pt}
```

to compensate the default used by the class; equivalent to `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}`  (50pt above and 40pt bellow) plus `titlesec` own vertical added space.

The last one  is different in the case of the label than in the title, as you observed.

[image: a]

[image: b]